# the IT specialist at work has denied access to external drives

Tags: external-hard-drive, usb-flash-drive

I am trying to access my 8GB USB drive at work, but it gives an error that says "access is denied", I know that they have resticted access at work. Is there anyway I can break into this from my local machine? weird thing is that my account is under the administrators group. Any suggestions?

Comment: Mustafa, welcome to Superuser.  Questions regarding circumvention of IT policy are usually not well received.

Comment: thank you.. 
yeah, I know that of course. I thought I would give it a shot.

Comment: If your employer is so restrictive, there may be a good chance they would be monitoring any circmuvention attempts, including posts like the one you just made.

Comment: haha,, everything is possible. The guy who is responsible for this is on vacation

Comment: You could post a question at Serverfault, http://serverfault.com, asking "If I needed to set up a policy to deny users external USB drive access, how would I do it?" and throw out some questions like "is it foolproof?" or "can they get around it?".

Comment: @hyperslug - so, what you're saying, we support questions that deal with practically the same thing, but mind how they are asked. One answer will result in bashing, the other in responses ...

Comment: @Idigas: Not saying that's the way I like it, but unfortunately that's true.

Comment: @Diago: Too localized?

Comment: @fretje Better? I still prefer localized since it applies to his network and his environment... Therefore localized.

Comment: @Diago: COME ON.. TOO localized !! this has to do with almost every developer 
the moment I posted this I was sure it's gonna be closed, but I thought someone will be keen enough to answer before it gets closed.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt the site owners want us to help you hack your employers systems.  In short, the restrictions are there for a reason.  Contact your internal support people or follow the rules.

Reasons that you might be restricted:

1. IT doesn't have enough time to verify everyone's storage device isn't infected with viruses.
2. Management is concerned with data theft - either by potentially disgruntled employees or the cleaning people/strangers who walk around your office and could find an open, logged on computer to sit in front of and attach a drive to either steal data or infect the network with malware.

Comment: I know these reason Multiverse, and I can see that you're an IT guy that respects the rules; however, I have been working here since long, and it is seriously getting boring with those restrictions, especially when you're free and you wanna kill some boredom. Even all webmails are resticted, flash is restricted, sending out attachments is restricted, facebook and myspace too, and everything that has to do with fun. Have some sympathy people –

Answer (score 1):

Well my enterprise follows the same. But there is an official escape to this. In my enterprise we have to contact the administrator and convince him for the data transfer. Yes it requires an official permission to do so but a genuine reason will not restrict him to transfer the data.

I will not suggest you to break your computer to transfer your stuff, if something goes wrong you have to pay huge price for maybe insignificant data which you have transfered.

Try to convince the admin and setup some kind of authorized stations from where you can transfer you data in or out.